# What makes a bundle id ineligible?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I created a new production certificate and provisioning profile using an existing app id.

In iTunes Connect, when adding a new app, I receive the error message "You have no eligible Bundle IDs for iOS apps. Register one here."

There doesn't appear to be any documentation on this issue in the Apple Developer Docs.

What makes a bundle id ineligible?

### **Updated Info:**

Going back to iTunes Connect a couple hours later, the bundle id was available and I created the new app.

My guess, a networking issue in the backend causes a delay between the creation of a bundle id in the developer portal and the availability of that id in iTunes Connect.

Still not sure "what makes a bundle id ineligible?"

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: This does not answer/solve the question specified by the user, but since it provides relevant information for a situation when the following error occurs:

> *You have no eligible Bundle IDs for iOS apps. Register one here.*

I am maintaining the response.

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

From what I could understand, if you have that error message (*You have no eligible Bundle IDs for iOS apps. Register one here.*) you need to **Create an App ID** and have a **distribution provisioning profile**.

Since from your question you already have the production profile, you probably need to create an app id.

They explain it how in the following link:
https://support.oomphhq.com/entries/22003453-Creating-App-IDs

You can check this website for more info on Adding a new app in iTunes Connect:
https://support.oomphhq.com/entries/22001486-6-Adding-a-New-App-in-iTunes-Connect

Comment: "I created a new production certificate and provisioning profile using an existing app id."

Comment: Oh. Ok. Did you enable iAds? I've seen this appear when you enable iAds you have to reconfigure the created app again.

Comment: No, the app is simple and does not have and ads of and frameworsk (healthkit, in-app purchases, ect.) I created a wildcard app id and another provisioning profile as a test, but got the same error message.

Comment: You are using the correct app id bundle right? (e.g. com.mattperejda.simpleapp)